# How to parameterize a `jq` expression to return either a selection or its complement?

Tags: jq

Let's assume I have two quite complex `jq` expressions, but that they only differ in that one returns the complement of the other, i.e., that the only difference between them is that one does `select(expression)` and the other does `select(expression|not)`.

Simplified example:

```bash
$ jq -n '$ARGS.positional[] | select( . > 2 )' --jsonargs 1 2 3 4 5
3
4
5
```

```bash
$ jq -n '$ARGS.positional[] | select( . > 2 | not )' --jsonargs 1 2 3 4 5
1
2
```

Instead of repeating these two different `jq` expressions in my code (these are, in reality, a handful of lines long each), passing a value into a single expression to switch between the two behaviours would be neat.

How can I do that?

---

Actual `jq` code (this filters RabbitMQ messages based on a file path encoded in the messages' payload):

```
map(
        # Add an array of pathnames that would match this message.  This
        # includes the pathnames of each parent directory, leading up to
        # and including the pathname of the file itself.
        .tmp_paths = [
                # The full pathname is part of a base64-encodod JSON blob.
                foreach (
                        .payload |
                        @base64d |
                        fromjson.filepath |
                        split("/")[]
                ) as $elem (
                        null;
                        . += $elem + "/";
                        .
                )

        ] |
        # The last element is the full file path and should not have a
        # trailing slash.
        .tmp_paths[-1] |= rtrimstr("/")
) |
[
        # Match the pathnames given as positional command line arguments
        # against the computed pathnames in the "tmp_paths" array in
        # each message.  Extract the messages with a match.
        JOIN(
                INDEX($ARGS.positional[]; .);
                .[];
                .tmp_paths[];
                if (.[1:] | any) then
                        .[0]
                else
                        empty
                end
        )
] |
# Deduplicate the extracted messages on the full pathname of the file.
# Then remove the "tmp_paths" array from each message and base64 encode
# them.
unique_by(.tmp_paths[-1])[] |
del(.tmp_paths) |
@base64
```

I'm assuming I need to modify that `if` statement somehow to make it either extract or discard the messages whose file paths match the pathnames given as positional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a boolean into the `jq` expression, and use an `if`-statement to switch between returning the selected set or its complement:

```bash
$ jq -n --argjson yes true '$ARGS.positional[] | select( . > 2 | if $yes then . else not end )' --jsonargs 1 2 3 4 5
3
4
5
```

```bash
$ jq -n --argjson yes false '$ARGS.positional[] | select( . > 2 | if $yes then . else not end )' --jsonargs 1 2 3 4 5
1
2
```

In the more complex `jq` expression, modify the `if` statement:

```
# Match the pathnames given as positional command line arguments
# against the computed pathnames in the "tmp_paths" array in
# each message.  Depending on the $yes boolean variable, extract
# or discard matching messages.
JOIN(
        INDEX($ARGS.positional[]; .);
        .[];
        .tmp_paths[];
        if (.[1:] | any | if $yes then . else not end) then
                .[0]
        else
                empty
        end
)
```

Note that it is with `if $yes then . else not end` that allows the variable `$yes` to act as a "toggle" for whether we want a set or its complement.  In both the simplified `select()` and the more complex `JOIN()`, this `if` statement acts on the boolean test result that determines whether an element should be part of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution described by @Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/744140/342404) is arguably the best way to go for all common cases, especially for occasional ones, as it is simple, readable, compact, and also reasonably quick.

You might consider a different approach perhaps if you use this switching behavior regularly enough to warrant a stable set-up, or if you are willing to go an extra mile to gain some speed.

The nice and simple way of a `if ... then ... else ... end` in fact has the downside of adding an extra comparison for each object of the stream. Such comparison happens to be a bit of a waste because its result is always known in advance, being a static input from the command line which never changes along the execution.

A possible way to remove that comparison is by using a function defined in modules, which you then select on the command line.

Consider:

```bash
# let's set the thing up
$ mkdir dot && echo 'def dot_or_not: .;' > dot/.jq
$ mkdir not && echo 'def dot_or_not: not;' > not/.jq
# now let's use it
$ seq 5 | jq 'include "./"; select ( . > 2 | dot_or_not )' -Ldot
3
4
5
$ seq 5 | jq 'include "./"; select ( . > 2 | dot_or_not )' -Lnot
1
2
```

In a few simple benchmarks on a uniprocessor VM this approach results 5 times quicker on average than the bare `if ... then ... else ... end`, though it may probably not weigh relevantly on the "economy" of the bigger computation you've shown.

I myself probably wouldn't go this far for such a simple operation... as it would get increasingly cumbersome and kludgy at each additional "switch" to handle, on top of other possible (more worthy) modules. Indeed I rather use modules for truly different variants of computations... but still.

---

Just for completeness, on the opposite end of the spectrum another approach may be like so:

```bash
$ seq 5 | jq 'select( . > 2 | [not,.][$yes] )' --argjson yes 1
3
4
5
$ seq 5 | jq 'select( . > 2 | [not,.][$yes] )' --argjson yes 0
1
2
```

or its cousin variant:

```bash
$ seq 5 | jq 'select( . > 2 | {(tostring):1}[$yes] )' --arg yes true 
3
4
5
$ seq 5 | jq 'select( . > 2 | {(tostring):1}[$yes] )' --arg yes false 
1
2
```

As compact to the eye as these approaches are, alas they also happen to be considerably slower (2-4x slower on my simple benchmarks) than a bare `if ... then ... else ... end`, as each of them adds the construction of 2 volatile objects and a lookup.